# Building docker image in GitLabCI pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have problem with GitLabCI, i am using the one on the gitlab.com .

I've got this in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
dockerization:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: dockerization
  variables:
      DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: "eu.gcr.io/sample-project/sample-app"
  script:
  - docker version
  - echo "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" > key.json
  - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io < key.json
  - docker push ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}
  only:
    - master
```

I receive error in pipeline:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           18.09.0
API version:       1.39
Go version:        go1.10.4
Git commit:        4d60db4
Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:46:51 2018
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I've tried adding `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"` to job or/and `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://localhost:2375"`, `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"`
but with no effect.

Is there any solution for this issue? Is something wrong with my pipeline declaration?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"` is the right solution, but you need to add

```
 services:
   - docker:dind
```

This will actually start the daemon on `docker` hostname. It's documented on [Building Docker images with GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor) (only the point number 3. is relevant to you)

But other topics on that page should be interesting to you further, like [Making docker-in-docker builds faster with Docker layer caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#making-docker-in-docker-builds-faster-with-docker-layer-caching)

More about services in gitlab CI can be found on [GitLab CI Services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/). In short it's like using docker-compose to have "companion" containers for your main one.